# insert an html tag using php plugin

Tags: plugins, css, html

I wanted to create a new `<div>` on top of the

`<div id="wpwrap">` in **adminheader.php**

and a closing tag below the `</body>` on **adminfooter.php**

should i just go create a new div manually? or use a plugin to insert those html  tags.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't edit the WP Core because it will break at the next update. I believe the easiest way is to use jQuery. Use a filter to add the jQuery code to the page.

```
function cystom_jquery_code() {
   echo '<script>
   jQuery("body").after("div class="myClass"></div>");
   jQuery("#wpwrap").before("<div class="beforeClass"></div>");
   </script>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'cystom_jquery_code');
```